# how can I listen for database changes using java

Tags: java, sql, actionlistener

is there any way to listen to database changes so that only when there is changes in the database , an action is performed in java ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812233/getting-events-from-a-database

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres has LISTEN/NOTIFY, Oracle has "database change notification".